# Practical Django Projects - Page 168

Tags: python, django, project

On page 168, there are two pieces of code :

```
def clean_password2(self):
   if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
      raise forms.ValidationError("You must type the same password each time")
   return self.cleaned_data['password2']

def clean(self):
   if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
      if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
         raise forms.ValidationError("You must type the same password each time")
   return self.cleaned_data
```

In the second case, the code checks whether 'password1' and 'password2' have any value. In the first case, there is no such check. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `clean_password2` you are validating the `password2` field so you are certain that it exists on that form and don't need to check for the existence of it in `self.cleaned_data`.  That doesn't mean they couldn't also check for the eixstence of `password1`, however.

The `clean` method is validating the whole form and has no guarantees of what is present.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. I am looking for a code which allows users to subscribe only if they have been invited to (a bit like on Quora). Where can I find that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the `clean_password2` method is doing a clean on a field, in this case the password2 field. ([**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute))

the `clean` method is called after the individual field validations. This is a good spot to do multi field validations according to the docs.

Read more [**`here`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).